# Converting base64 into a functional JPEG in Typescript/angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, image, base64

I am running cropperjs on a static image in the browser(retrieved from a nodejs server in jpeg format), it returns a preview in a different image that is in base64. Im trying to take that data and save the modified image back to the server in the original jpeg format.
I've tried a few different things, but this is the latest:

```
saveCroppedImage(){  

     var split = this.imageDestination.split(','); // parsing out data:image/png;base64,
     var croppedImage = split[1];                  // assigning the base64 to a variable
     var blob = new Blob([croppedImage],{type: 'image/jpeg'}); //changing the base64->Blob
     var file = new File([blob],'cropped.jpeg');  //theoretically changing the blob->jpeg
     this.newCroppedImage = file;
}
```

I then upload the file to the server and it is corrupted.

Comment: is it really jpeg or is it png? In the first comment in your code you mention *data:image/png*.

Comment: It is a png, sorry I tried converting if to both when attempting to debug the issue this peace of code was the jpeg attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out with some help of the interweb:

This is the info I had to include with the file creation, and it did have to stay a png to work.

```
public file = (theBlob: Blob): File =>
    {return new File([theBlob],'croppedImage.png',{lastModified:new 
    Date().getTime(), type:'image/png'}) 
 }
```

saveCroppedImage() {

```
    var split = this.imageDestination.split(',');
    console.log(this.imageDestination)
    var croppedImage = split[1]
    this.blob = blobUtil.base64StringToBlob(croppedImage);
    this.newCroppedImage =this.file(this.blob);
    this.onFileChange();
```

}